# VIM: go to end of the current word and switch into insert mode

Tags: vim

I can use `ea`.
But it's too much =). I would like to use one single key.

Can it be combined into one key?

UPD: You can use `nnoremap _ ea`. Where _ is any key. I'm wondering is there any default way to do that?

Comment: `nnoremap _ ea` where you may put your key at `_`?

Comment: @j1-lee yep, that seems to be working. So, VIM doesn't have a key for that (without remapping)?

Comment: For me after a few months the `ea` had become ingrained so it feels like a singe operation. Also `Ea` is a nice modified version that gets you to the end of a chunk of text delimited by white-space like `(this)` which you would need _another_ mapping for... and then you're into the territory of undoing vim's well thought out editing operations... it's better in such cases become comfortable with Vim's default behaviour (in the end it will pay off more than the single keypress saved from the proposed mapping)

Answer (score 3):

```
ea
```

*is* the "default way to do that".

If it's really too much for you, create your own mapping, as hinted in the comments:

```
nnoremap <key> ea
```

See `:help key-notation` and `:help normal-index`. Note that there is not a single unused lowercase alphabetic key in normal mode so that strategy invariably leads to compromises.